# Where can I find free sound effects?

Tags: sound-effects

Free sound effects sites. One per answer.

Please make sure that you are not posting a duplicate. If you see duplicates, please vote them down and comment to let the author know.

Comment: Making this community wiki since it's worthwhile information, but is basically a list of good resources

Comment: I would suggest just recording them yourself. You might be able to get better results that way and it can be more fun.

Answer (score 15):

## [Freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/)

More than 290,000 user-uploaded sounds licensed under various [Creative Commons licenses](http://www.freesound.org/help/faq/). Depending on the license, the sounds have no terms, require attribution and/or prohibit commercial use. It has [advanced search](http://www.freesound.org/search/?q=&f=duration%3A%5B0%20TO%20*%5D&s=score%20desc&advanced=1&g=1).

Downloading sounds requires a free account.

Uploaded sounds are moderated by [volunteers moderators](https://www.freesound.org/help/moderators/) for legality.

There is a [sound request forum](http://www.freesound.org/forum/sample-requests/).

*This post has been edited by a volunteer Freesound.org moderator*

Answer (score 6):

## [ccmixter](http://ccmixter.org/view/media/samples/browse)

Creative commons licensed audio files and sample packs.

Comment: this is music, not sounds, and should be put in a question asking for free music if there is one.

Comment: There are definitely just sounds here as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Lasonotheque](http://www.lasonotheque.org/en/)

> Founded by Joseph SARDIN in 2005, the music library aims to provide
> free and for all, a wide range of sounds and noises of a much higher
> quality than those typically found on the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

## [SoundDogs](http://www.sounddogs.com/)

I used this site when I needed to get random noises for a film.

Searching generic search terms probably won't get you very far, you tend to have to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 4):

### [FreeSFX](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/sfx)

A library of over 7300 sounds in various categories. Requires login to download. Requires [attribution](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/info/eula/) for use.

Allows user uploads. The site owners [moderate quality](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/faq/) but there is no statement about moderation of legality.

Answer (score 2):

### [SafeMusicList](http://www.safemusiclist.com)

If you're looking for free and legal sound effects or music check out this online directory:

In particular, the [free music](http://www.safemusiclist.com/category/free-music/) category.

Comment: music is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

### BBC Sound Effects Library

There are a number of torrents that contain the complete, 60 CD collection of royalty-free BBC sound effects.

Searching for "bbc royalty free sound effects library" has a number of results that mention  "free" and "royalty-free".

Comment: Keep in mind that a lot of these have been used hundreds or thousand times over, so even casual listeners may recognise them as re-used samples. There's a particular fire engine horn sample in there that's been used in at least a few hundred games, movies, TV episodes, etc.

Comment: somebody upvoted this? This is a suggestion to search for illegally distributed sounds on torrent websites. BBC sounds are not free to share. The user is already deleted, this post should too.

Answer (score 1):

### [DownloadFreeSound](http://www.downloadfreesound.com)

is a new free online sound effect library.

Great sound fx and music.

Answer (score 0):

## [Sweet Sound Effects](http://sweetsoundeffects.com/)

Sound effects produced by YouTube video producer Zach King:

Not too many sounds, but they are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

## [Freesoundsfx.com](http://freesoundsfx.com/)

- You can download mp3 sound effects (320kb/s) available for commercial projects too.
- You can't share this sound (unless is part of your project and is not the main focus) but you can share the link to site.